# Converting 16 bit long Hex value to a color

Tags: file-format, decompress, hexadecimal

I am currently trying to reverse engineer some game files. I have found the exact location of each graphic element, but now I am stuck trying to convert their data to "readable" rgb code. They use 16 bit long Hex values (0xC306 or 110000110000 converts to R:0 G:219 B:24)

The file is written in little endian. Could someone tell me how they convert it?

> More examples:
>
> (0xCFC0 -> RGB 198 24 123)
>
> (0xFFF0 -> RGB 247 28 255)
>
> (0xFF00 -> RGB 0 28 255)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be stored in byte-reversed order from what you gave with a standard 5-6-5 bit encoding and then scaled to a maximum of 255 for each.

## 0xC0CF (0b1100000011001111)

R: 24 (0b11000) * 255/31 = **197**  G: 6 (0b000110) * 255/63 = **24**  B: 15 (0b01111) * 255/31 = **123**

## 0xF0FF (0b1111000011111111)

R: 30 (0b11110) * 255/31 = **247**  G: 7 (0b000111) * 255/63 = **28**  B: 31 (0b11111) * 255/31 = **255**

## 0x00FF (0b0000000011111111)

R: 0 (0b00000) * 255/31 = **0**  G: 7 (0b000111) * 255/63 = **28**  B: 31 (0b11111) * 255/31 = **255**